# Flask-Security Login Functional testing

Tags: unit-testing, flask

I'm trying to do some functional testing on Flask view functions.
Currently I'm using login, logout from Flask Security module and when I try to follow the login and logout guide from flask's documentation(http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/#logging-in-and-out), the 'post' of login seems to not working. I've been getting this same error when I try to post using requests module too. 
My Flask-Security's login endpoint is /login_test/

Below are piece of my unit test code.

```
class TestUser(unittest.TestCase):
    #run before each test
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = app.test_client()
        db.create_all()


    def tearDown(self):
        #db.session.remove()
        #DropEverything().drop_db()
        pass

    def login(self, email, password):
        return self.client.post('/login_test/', data=dict(
            email=email,
            password=password
        ), follow_redirects=False)

    def logout(self):
        return self.client.get('/logout', follow_redirects=True)

    def test_login_logout(self):
        response = self.client.post('/login_test', data=dict(
            email='admin',
            password='admin'
        ), follow_redirects=False)
        self.assertIn(b'You logged in', response.data)
```

The error message that I got after hitting test_login_logout is like below. The below is when I hit the url with '/login_test'

```
Ran 1 test in 0.187s

FAILED (failures=1)

Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 58, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 600, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/Users/genom003dm/PycharmProjects/sample_accessioning_dev/app/tests/user_management_testing.py", line 38, in test_login_logout
    ), follow_redirects=False)
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 801, in post
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/testing.py", line 127, in open
    follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 764, in open
    response = self.run_wsgi_app(environ, buffered=buffered)
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 677, in run_wsgi_app
    rv = run_wsgi_app(self.application, environ, buffered=buffered)
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 884, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1590, in dispatch_request
    self.raise_routing_exception(req)
  File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1576, in raise_routing_exception
    raise FormDataRoutingRedirect(request)
flask.debughelpers.FormDataRoutingRedirect: b'A request was sent to this URL (http://localhost/login_test) but a redirect was issued automatically by the routing system to "http://localhost/login_test/".  The URL was defined with a trailing slash so Flask will automatically redirect to the URL with the trailing slash if it was accessed without one.  Make sure to directly send your POST-request to this URL since we can\'t make browsers or HTTP clients redirect with form data reliably or without user interaction.\n\nNote: this exception is only raised in debug mode'
```

If I change the URL to /login_test/ then I get HTTP 400 errors. I'm assuming that this is happening due to the fact that I'm missing form object for login? (but in this case I don't have form object because I'm trying just trying to login with post api).

I want to know is there a way to login using flask-security's /login_test/ url.

Thanks

Comment: First, can you clarify how you defined your routes in the main app. with or without trailing slashes. Flask considers that in it's routing mechanism.

Comment: @ Mekicha I don't have to create my own view for login because flask security does it for me. All I had to do was to set the login end point at the config file. I've set it as /login_test/

Comment: What response are you getting now?

Comment: When I put /login_test/ as a route, I get HTTP 400 error. I think that flask security is expecting some kind of a form object for the post? but in this case I don't have any forms since I just want to login a user via api.

Comment: You can take a look at the sample test from flas-security on github. https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/develop/tests/test_passwordless.py your code looks okay to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer. The reason why I was only seeing HTTP 400 errors instead of the specifics of HTTP 400 errors are because I put the error handling on Flask app and it just showed me 400 rather than what the actual error was. Once I removed the HTTP 400 error handling, it was saying that the CSRF token was missing. So what I did was to WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False in app config file.